# JqueryUI datepicker returns invalid date on dateFormat

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers with `dateFromat` property and I get the following values in debugger:

`dateText = "27.05.2016"`

`begin = Invalid Date {}`

`d=NaN`

`m=NaN`

`y=NaN`

Is there a way to get this date format working for my example? I think that the `Date()` function can't convert to date the value of this date format...

Example without `dateFormat`: http://jsbin.com/yuxaliqoba/edit?html,output

Example with `dateFormat`: http://jsbin.com/hihidihexo/edit?html,output

```
  <input class="datepicker begin" type="text" />
  <input class="datepicker end" type="text"/>
  <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker.begin").datepicker({
            minDate: '+2d',
            maxDate: '+2y',
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
               // Resolve the current date
               var begin = new Date($(this).val());
               var d = begin.getDate();
               var m = begin.getMonth();
               var y = begin.getFullYear();
               // Update your target date
               $(".datepicker.end").datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m, d+2));
               $(".datepicker.end").datepicker( "option", "minDate",  d - 10);
            }
        });
        $(".datepicker.end").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            minDate: '+4d',
            maxDate: '+2y'
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that 27.05.2016 is an invalid date. As you can see in this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/mp64p6Lw/2/

Instantiating a new date object with 27.05.2016 returns "Invalid Date". So calls to get*() will not return what you expect.

I recommend changing the date format into ISO 8601 date format so your date manipulations are more stable.

```
var dateISO = new Date('2016-05-27');
```

You would need to change `dd.mm.yy` to `yy-mm-dd` when you instantiate your datepicker.